# ST_Intersects with subquery in Spatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, st-intersects

I am having issues with what seems to be a very simple spatial query with a sub-query in Spatialite. I am trying to find all the buildings (poly) that intersect with a service area (poly), but only buildings that have a specific subtype code and with stories greater than a value (see query below). I am assuming it is a syntax error, but cannot seem to figure it.

```
SELECT b.pkid, b.subtype, b.stories
FROM bldg AS b, service_area AS a
  (SELECT b.subtype, b.stories
   FROM bldg
   WHERE subtype IN ('x', 'y', 'z') AND stories > 16)
WHERE ST_Intersects(b.geometry, a.geometry)
```

#### ERROR

```
Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS SELECT b.pkid, b.subtype, b.stories
FROM bldg AS b, service_area AS a
  (SELECT b.subtype, b.stories
   FROM bldg
   WHERE subtype IN ('x', 'y', 'z') AND stories > 16)
WHERE ST_Intersects(b.geometry, a.geometry): 1 - near "(": syntax error
```

#### EDIT

Query to select desired subtype and buildings > 16 stories
[image]

ST_Intersects query - buildings and service area (buildings shorter than 16)
[image]

I did get the following query to work, but its not a subquery and not the most optimal:

```
 SELECT b.pkid, b.subtype, b.stories
 FROM bldg AS b, service_area AS a
 WHERE ST_Intersects(b.geometry, a.geometry) AND b.subtype IN ('x', 'y', 'z') AND b.stories > 16
```

Comment: What results do you actually get and what where you expecting? Can you show a sample of the data in `bldg` and `service_area`? Use something like `SELECT stories, subtype, AsEWKT(geometry) FROM bldg WHERE stories > 16 LIMIT 5` and `SELECT AsEWKT(geometry) FROM service_area LIMIT 5` and put those into the question.

Comment: When I run the query it results in an error. What I am expecting is two things:
1) only buildings that have a story > 16 and have a subtype code of x, y or z
2) the results from 1 (sub-selection) that intersect with the service area

Comment: What error? We can't see your screen, and we know you are deep in it, but please help us to help you. Also, where did `subtype_de` come from, and where is the geometry information I asked for?

Comment: @BradHards I added images with the two specific queries that you requested.  I also added the error. The subtype_de, which I fixed, is the actual column name. I cleaned the column names, table names, and attributes to be cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "," in your FROM before "("